# Kivy label only shows last element of a text loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, feedparser

Hi i am Using Feedparser to fetch rss news and display the news headlines

```
import feedparser
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

 def build(self):
    d=feedparser.parse('https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewsFeed&feed=rss&categories=Published&notcategories=No%20publish%7CArchived%7cAutoArchived%7cdisputed&namespace=0&count=15&ordermethod=categoryadd&stablepages=only')
    print (len(d['entries']))
    for post in d['entries']:
        news=post.title
        print(news)
    return Label(text=news)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

i.e`news=post.title` using a kivy label.

Originally the output is as follows:

```
Study suggests Mars hosted life-sustaining habitat for millions of years
NASA's TESS spacecraft reports its first exoplanet
Russians protest against pension reform
US rapper Mac Miller dies at home in Los Angeles
Creativity celebrated at Fan Expo Canada 2018 in Toronto
Brisbane, Australia Magistrates Court charges two cotton farmers with $20m fraud  
Fossil genome shows hybrid of two extinct species of human
Singer Aretha Franklin, 'queen of soul', dies aged 76
New South Wales, Australia government says entire state in winter 2018 drought
Real Madrid agrees with Chelsea FC to sign goalkeeper Thibaut Courtois
```

But,Whenever i run the program the Kivy app only shows the Last headline in the loop

i.e:`Real Madrid agrees with Chelsea FC to sign goalkeeper Thibaut Courtois`

Any ideas about what im missing on? any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, `news` is overwritten in the loop so it takes the last value, a possible solution is to concatenate the texts:

```
import feedparser
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        url = 'https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewsFeed&feed=rss&categories=Published&notcategories=No%20publish%7CArchived%7cAutoArchived%7cdisputed&namespace=0&count=15&ordermethod=categoryadd&stablepages=only'
        d=feedparser.parse(url)
        news = ""
        for post in d['entries']:
            news += post.title + "\n"
        return Label(text=news)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Another option is to use a `BoxLayout` and create several `Label`s:

```
import feedparser
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        url = 'https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewsFeed&feed=rss&categories=Published&notcategories=No%20publish%7CArchived%7cAutoArchived%7cdisputed&namespace=0&count=15&ordermethod=categoryadd&stablepages=only'
        d=feedparser.parse(url)
        for post in d['entries']:
            label = Label(text=post.title)
            root.add_widget(label)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: My god! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Harvindersingh If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.